# How do I update multiple records in a table with a single query? (postgresql)

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a table with the name of a group of animals.

It looks like this:

[image: image_1]

Suppose you want to update the data for groups.

- Now, in the record with `group_id` = `2`, the `quantity` changes from `2` to `1`.
- In a record with `group_id` = `3`, `different_aviaries` change from `false` to `true`.
- In a record with `group_id` = `4`, the `group_name` changes to `null`, and the quantity to `0`.

The result should be like this:

[image: image_2]

How can this be done in a single request?

P.S I greatly simplified the table in the example. In fact, it may be necessary to update 40 records at a time. In addition, the columns in the table from Example 5, but in fact there are 14.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have used that isn't working as you need it to.

Comment: I do not know how this Sql code will look in principle.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#updates has everything you want to know.

Comment: So.. did my answer worked for you @ВасилийПупкин?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [Laravel Batch package](https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch).  From the readme:

> ```
> use App\Models\User;
>
> $userInstance = new User;
> $value = [
>      [
>          'id' => 1,
>          'status' => 'active',
>          'nickname' => 'Mohammad'
>      ] ,
>      [
>          'id' => 5,
>          'status' => 'deactive',
>          'date' => Carbon::now()
>      ] ,
> ];
> $index = 'id';
>
> Batch::update($userInstance, $value, $index);
> ```

You could easily adjust it to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done in native SQL. But whether with an ORM or natively it's a bad idea, especially with 40 rows and 14 columns. If this is a one time operation then just write the individual updates. That would be a much safer option because as this larger the probability of making an error vastly increases. If it not a one time operation then there's nothing to predict this variability in advance; so each becomes a one time thing.  
But it can be done; Just don't:

```
update animal_groups
   set quantity = case when group_id = 2 then 1
                       when group_id = 4 then 0 
                       else quantity
                  end
     , different_aviaries = case when group_id = 3 then true
                                 else different_aviaries
                            end
     ,  group_name = case when group_id = 4 then null
                          else group_name
                     end                      
 where group_id in (2,3,4);
```

Note the quantity update must account for both value changes as the column name can be a LEFT VALUE only once in the statement.

Comment: Thank. Today I wrote a method that generates SQL code.

 I tested it in the postman passing parameters and everything was updated.

And further, this is not one time operation, but is this the right approach or can one do better?